# Filter object permutation in List<List<Entry<String, Double>>> with Java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Starting from a list of `Entry<String, Double>` I just found all the combination with the following method:

```
public static <T> Stream<List<T>> getCombinationsStream(List<T> list) {   
    return LongStream.range(1 , 1 << list.size())
            .mapToObj(l -> bitMapToList(l, list));
}
```

Now I want to filter the resulted Lists of Entry to only those who have the sum of all its value

> entry.getValue()

equal to a known number.

```
List<Entry<String, Double>> myList;
double value = 100; 

//...

List<List<Entry<String, Double>>> allCombinations = Permutations.getCombinationsStream(myList)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

after that, my goal is to take only the Entry list with the smallest size that has the sum of its value equal to my value (i.e 100)

example:

```
/*
* allCombinatinos example 
*
* [[k1=90.0],[k2=30],[k3=70],
* [k1=90.0, k2=30],[k1=90.0, k3=70],[k2=30, k3=70],
* [k1=90.0, k2=30, k3=70]]
*/
```

with this lists the expected result will be only one list:

```
//result
[k2=30, k3=70]
```

I think that this problem can be handled with .filter() and other stream operation, but I don't know how to figure out.

Comment: So in the end, you want a `List<Entry<String, Double>>` with the double parts' sum being the required value (100)?

Comment: Yes, you're right

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way to go about it:

```
Optional<List<Entry<String, Double>>> min = 
        getCombinationsStream(myList)
                 .filter(l -> l.stream()
                               .mapToDouble(Map.Entry::getValue).sum() == value)
                 .min(Comparator.comparingInt(List::size));
```

filters with the said criteria then finds the list of entries with minimum size.